# Php syntax error when i run it

Tags: php

I'm try to get content form another site. Following is the php code. But when i run it, it's show error message.

Error message:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'â€“' (T_STRING) in D:\Software\Installed\xampp\htdocs
\test\index.php on line 10
```

Php code:

```
<?php
function get_string_between($string, $start, $end)
{
$string = " ".$string;
$ini = strpos($string,$start);
if ($ini == 0)
return "";
$ini += strlen($start);

$len = strpos($string, $end, $ini) – $ini; // this is line number 10.

return substr($string,$ini,$len);
}
//Initialize the Curl session
$ch = curl_init();

//Set curl to return the data instead of printing it to the browser.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
//Set the URL
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.test.org/");
//Execute the fetch
$data = curl_exec($ch);

echo $da=get_string_between($data,'imgs/topdown.gif">','imgs/topdown.gif');
//Close the connection
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: That's not a minus sign on line 10.  Try to replace it with a `-`.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Add your comment as an answer, even if it is short.

Comment: Your page encoding should be utf-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `-` in your line 10 it not a normal minus sign.  It's another ASCII character, this is what is messing it up.

Try to replace that character with a minus sign.

Comment: One more question sometime i can't see other website content using this function. Is there anything need to add?

Comment: @Babu: What do you mean "I can't see other content"?

Comment: Well, if i put another website address to curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.anotherwebsite.com/"); then it's show empty page.

Comment: @Babu: Have you checked what `curl_exec` returns?  Are you sure it contains the string(s) you are searching for?